# Writing R package: how to import hidden functions from another package?

Tags: r, package, hidden

I am building a R package that I would like to submit on the CRAN. As explained in the topic, my issue is that I need to use hidden functions from another package. I don't know how edit the NAMESPACE file (and DESCRIPTION maybe) in order to handle such hidden functions. I could use the "Depend" argument, but this seems not desirable for a R package submitted to the CRAN (but I am maybe wrong?). What I have done is that I rewrote the functions and export them as if it was my own functions, but it seems not a proper way to achieve my goal... So, my question is, how to import these hidden functions in a proper way? Note that all these hidden functions are used for only one of my R functions.

Comment: `Import`ing that package to your namespace doesn't help ?

Comment: I don't think CRAN accepts packages that call functions like `package:::fun`, so you'll have to ask to the maintainer to export the function, or if you can include the function in your own package.

Comment: Thanks for these quick answers! Indeed, it is the same issue as the other post. Thank you again.